# iteration is giving me an error : For-loop range must have an 'iterator()' method

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I'm new to kotlin and android development in general. I'm following [this youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yjF25NlOnkY) to setup and turn on/off bluetooth. Every line is working except iterating over the paired devices, it is giving me an error :
"For-loop range must have an 'iterator()' method"
val pairedDevices: Unit

My Code in the MainActivity.kt:

```
package com.example.btprinting

import android.Manifest
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothManager
import android.content.Context
import android.content.Intent
import android.content.pm.PackageManager
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.activity.ComponentActivity
import androidx.activity.compose.setContent
import androidx.activity.result.ActivityResultCallback
import androidx.activity.result.ActivityResultLauncher
import androidx.activity.result.contract.ActivityResultContracts
import androidx.compose.foundation.border
import androidx.compose.foundation.horizontalScroll
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.*
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Arrangement.Absolute.Center
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Arrangement.Absolute.aligned

import androidx.compose.material.*
import androidx.compose.material3.Button
import androidx.compose.material3.MaterialTheme
import androidx.compose.material3.OutlinedButton
import androidx.compose.material3.Surface
import androidx.compose.material3.Text
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.ui.Alignment
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color
import androidx.compose.ui.platform.LocalContext
import androidx.compose.ui.text.font.FontWeight
import androidx.compose.ui.text.style.TextAlign
import androidx.compose.ui.tooling.preview.Preview
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.dp
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.sp
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat
import com.example.btprinting.ui.theme.BTprintingTheme


// =

lateinit var bluetoothManager: BluetoothManager
lateinit var bluetoothAdapter: BluetoothAdapter
lateinit var takePermission:ActivityResultLauncher<String>
lateinit var takeResultLauncher: ActivityResultLauncher<Intent>




// =



class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {




    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)



        //dr vipin

        bluetoothManager=getSystemService(BLUETOOTH_SERVICE) as BluetoothManager
        bluetoothAdapter=bluetoothManager.adapter
        takePermission=registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.RequestPermission()){
            if (it)
            {
                val intent =Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE)
                takeResultLauncher.launch(intent)

            }else
            {
                Toast.makeText(applicationContext,"Bluetooth Permission is not Granted",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
        }

        takeResultLauncher=registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult(),
            ActivityResultCallback {
                    result->
                if (result.resultCode== RESULT_OK){
                    Toast.makeText(applicationContext,"Bluetooth ON",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                } else
                {
                    Toast.makeText(applicationContext,"Bluetooth OFF",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                }
            })

        //end of dr vipin







        setContent {
            BTprintingTheme {
                // A surface container using the 'background' color from the theme
                Surface(
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                    color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background
                ) {
                    //Greeting2("Android")
                    Greeting()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}



@Composable
fun Greeting() {
    //Explanation !!
    //The Toast.makeText() method requires three parameters:
    //
    //Context object: You need to pass the application context or the Activity context.
    //- Using LocalContext.current we can get the Context object.
    //- LocalContext.current can be used only from within a Composable function. Such as we are using it within Column() function which is a composable function. LocalContext.current cannot be used within a function which is not marked with @composable annotation.
    val context = LocalContext.current


    Column(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center
    ) {
        Text("Bluetooth ON/OFF Application",fontSize=20.sp,
            fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold,textAlign= TextAlign.Center,
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()
        )
        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(20.dp))
        OutlinedButton(onClick = {
            takePermission.launch(android.Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT)

        }) {
            Text("Bluetooth ON",fontSize=30.sp,
                fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold)
        }
        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(20.dp))
        OutlinedButton(onClick = {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Bluetooth Is Off.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                //bluetooth off button
        }) {
            Text("Bluetooth OFF",fontSize=30.sp,
                fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold)
        }
        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(20.dp))
        OutlinedButton(onClick = {
            val data:StringBuffer= StringBuffer()
            val pairedDevices =

                if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                    context,
                    Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT
                ) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
            ) {
                // TODO: Consider calling
                //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
                // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
                //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
                //                                          int[] grantResults)
                // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
                // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.

            } else {

                }
            bluetoothAdapter.bondedDevices



//                for (device in  pairedDevices ) {
//                    data.append("Device Name=" + device.name + "\nDevice Address" + device.address)
//                }
                if (data.isEmpty()) {
                    Toast.makeText(context,"No Bluetooth Paired Device Found",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(context, data, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                }


        }) {
            Text("Display Paired Devices",fontSize=30.sp,
                fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold)
        }
    }

}
```

it is giving me an error :

```
"For-loop range must have an 'iterator()' method"
val pairedDevices: Unit
```

I intentiionally created this in a no activity project so I can focus on the bluetooth api and that part is under control but everything I tried still kept giving an error.

After reading tons of material online, I still don't know how to fix this error. So I'm reaching to the community and hopefully someone experienced enough will be able to give me a solution on how to iterate over the paired devices. Clearly the iteration is missing something but I'm unable to figure it out. Any help?

Comment: You're trying to assign `pairedDevices` via an if-else expression. Except nothing is inside either the `if` block or the `else` block, so nothing is being returned. And since you're also letting the compiler infer the type of `pairedDevices`, the inferred type is `Unit` (which is not a type that can be iterated by a for loop). I suspect that `bluetoothAdapter.bondedDevices` line is supposed to be _inside_ the `else` block. But I have no idea what you should be doing in the `if` block.